# Which shortcut to use flags on top 'find'/'replace' dialog in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I toggle flags like 'Match Case', 'Words' in find panel?
How can I replace all occurrences without using a mouse?

Comment: I've struggled with 'replace all' for a couple of months (using tab a couple of times). I'm posting in case someone else also didn't know the shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule for underscored options like [image] is to use combination of `alt + underscored letter`, so in this case it would be `alt + x`.

In case of the buttons `Replace`, `Replace all` and `Exclude` underscored letter shows when you use `alt` button. The shortcuts are `alt + p` for replace, `alt + a` for replace all and `alt + l` for exclude.

Comment: Note that for Alt shortcuts to work in dialogs the **Disable mnemonics in controls** option in Settings(Preferences) | Appearance & Behavior | [Appearance](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/appearance-2.html) settings should be **not enabled**.

Comment: I didn't know about it. Is there a way to use some shortcut if this option is enabled? What is the purpose of this option?

Comment: As describe this option enables/disables ability to use mnemonics in dialogs: that is the shortcuts for the menu items which you can use with the Alt key.

Comment: This feature is pretty much busted from 2021 onwards. Sad.. because I had like you used it frequently